# Adding a hyperlink to the checkbox in the contact form 7

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

I have added a required checkbox field to contact form 7 to fill before form submission. But I need to give link "Terms and Condition" to the page. I searched and tried in many ways, but i cannot find the correct way. If someone can help me I really appreciate it. Thanks in advance

This is the checkbox field I already added

```
[checkbox* term_and_conditions class:required "I can confirm I have read and accepted the Terms and Conditions."]
```

Comment: Did you try just wrapping one or a few word with a a-tag manually?

Comment: [checkbox* term_and_conditions class:required “I can .. <a href=‘http://www..yourlink.com/page‘>terms and..</a>“] like that

Comment: @Luckyfella thank you for your answer, I tried in this way, but it does not give the desired out put

Comment: Is your plugin up to date? Doesn’t work with older versions. I just had to do the same and it works perfectly like posted. What output do you get right now?

Comment: @Luckyfella Iit displays with the <a> tags with the href.

Answer (score 7):

It should work like said in my comment but maybe an even better way would be to use the acceptance filed-type that is build especially for that kind of checkboxes.

```
[acceptance term_and_conditions class:required] I can confirm I have read and accepted the <a href="http://www.your-domain.com/terms-page">Terms and Conditions</a>.[/acceptance]
```

In the contact form 7 edit page go to the tab additional settings and add:

```
acceptance_as_validation: on
```

Comment: If the answer helped you solving your problem feel free to accept it, or not. Would help others to see that it is solved and does not need further investigation.

Comment: I tried this answer, but it does not display the content as i need. It shows only the check box. But I need to show the content and need to link Terms and Condition to an another page once user clicks on it, Any way thank you for your help

Comment: I had the same issue before I updated the plugin..

Comment: @Luckyfella, thank you for adding the acceptance_as_validation detail. It is  very useful and I did not know it. Obviously, your answer works.

Comment: @turzifer Thank you - I‘m glad it was useful to you!